# Current source not working in LTspice XVII

Tags: ltspice, simulation, cmos, current-source

I am trying to implement a circuit (CMOS implementation of DVTC) with the help of LTspice (I'm very new to this software.)

The built in current source component is not working in LTspice. Following is the circuit diagram and the error that I get while running the application:

**Circuit**
[image]

**Error**
[image]

I was facing same error in case of NMOS and PMOS but I resolved that using some external library and components.

I have updated my LTspice and also tried downloading it from scratch but still I'm getting the same error. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I am not sure the V1-V2 statement in the .dc command is alright . Try with only V1. Also open I1 advanced settings and check if there is anything strange entered there. PS: why do you have two separate symbols each for NMOS and PMOS ?? Maybe one of those symbols is fishy ?

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket somewhere.  You have a { and need a matching }.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please rename all the components so that they don’t have a single quotation mark in their name. The single quotation mark corresponds to curly bracket and it confuses the LTSpice.